# Converting C "srand(time(NULL));" to D language

Tags: d, srand

What's the equivalent in D language for C statement `srand(time(NULL));`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at std.random:
https://dlang.org/phobos/std_random.html

There you can find the uniform function, seed and unpredictableSeed.